# AngularJS initial route controller not loaded. Subsequent ones are fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a HTML5 pushState app. For some reason or another, the controller responsible for the route that I hit initiall is not loaded when I first load the up. If I click around, everything is fine.

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening, a demo can be viewed here: http://osumo.paas.allizom.org

This used to be okay. I did some work today on some components that had nothing to do with the `$routeProvider` and it just broke.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Initial thought is how foundation is being initialized in combination with angularjs.  I am checking into it before I post an answer.  Did you just add foundation?

Comment: No. Foundation has been there all along.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wont go down that trail then.

Comment: You should setup a plnkr that illustrates the problem - I am finding it very hard to help you debug, there's too much there.

Comment: @ultimatebuster, your controllers are not being called without a click to another path. You have your entire app.js wrapped in a function, what do you have that is calling that function other than when you are changing scope?  Also you do not have to wrap the controllers in a function usually, is there a reason you are doing that?

Comment: Figured out the problem. See answer.

Answer (score 1):

So to answer this question, it gets quite.. interesting. The problem actually came from this line: https://github.com/shuhaowu/osumo/commit/c539d8048696152ad75f13a6d965160381b89a21#L2L22

The reason of this is actually quite logical, though it is a big pain to figure out. Basically I'm doing things that I should not be doing (as often that happens).

So first thing first, the code is setting a locale when a service is being initialized. That itself is no big deal, as we want to set the locale to `navigator.language`. This code is here: https://github.com/shuhaowu/osumo/blob/c539d8048696152ad75f13a6d965160381b89a21/static/js/develop/services/appservice.js#L165

When this gets called, an event gets triggered and this event will cause a bunch of directive to change its texts. Again, this is no big deal. https://github.com/shuhaowu/osumo/blob/c539d8048696152ad75f13a6d965160381b89a21/static/js/vendors/l10n.js#L23

Here comes the trouble. The version of the code that's problematic included `$rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply()` as when the library is designed it is assumed that setLocale could be called outside of the angular world and it wants to be a little magical so that things just works when the event fires. While I cannot be certain exactly what is going on in Angular, my guess would be that `$scope.$$phase` is not set at this point as we're still initializing the different components. Calling `$apply` here caused angular to start applying to the page, which causes the page to never load.

Lesson learned: don't do stupid stuff.

Comment: Nice!  And very big props for the code behind the issue and explanation.